# Store colors in common project to share between Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm developing an app with Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS. I would like to keep my color values (hex, rgb, or whatever) in a common project so that they can be accessed by both the Android and iOS projects. Is there a way to do this? I'm also using MvvmCross so is there a plugin for this? Or is this a bad idea?

I'm going to be using the colors in the Android layout files (.xml files) and back-end code for both platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this? [Share colors between platforms]

Yes, you can use [`MvxColor`](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/color).* (With some limitations)

> I'm also using MvvmCross so is there a plugin for this?

`MvxColor` is available via a plugin on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Plugin.Color/).

> Or is this a bad idea? [Share colors between platforms]
>
> > **Use Case**: I'm going to be using the colors in the Android layout files (.xml files) and back-end code for both platforms.

`MvxColor` will not work directly in XML. But can be used through bindings or assigning colors via the code behind. Therefore, if you want to use any Android XML design time tools with colors then `MvxColor` will not work.

Comment: I guess it would be ok to set all the colors in the code behind. What about having a common project with all the images shared between both platforms? It sounds like a crazy/stupid idea to me, but am curious if there's a second opinion on that?

Comment: And I just thought of something else...sometimes I have layouts in my `drawables` folder, and themes that are all .xml...so I guess having a the colors in a common project is not worth it...

Comment: @Darius, Yeah, the limitation of `MvxColor` is that it is statically defined so it would not be accessible to use via XML resources. You could make look into a T4 transform to generate an Android XML color resource file so that you can access the colors in XML resources.